# Python - File Directory Issue

Tags: python, file

so i'm going to be as in depth as possible, here's my problem:

I'm using the `turtle.addshape()` command to add images onto the turtle. In order to do this I have to do `turtle.addshape(C:\Users\Username Here\Desktop\Game\Images\an image.gif)`

The problem is with this, is that if I were to distribute my file, it would search for `C:\Users\Username Here\Desktop\Game`

I want it to find the image, WHEREVER the file is and WHOEVER is using it, for example:

C:\Users\ `the computers user here` \ `where ever the file is located here` \Game\Images\an image.gif

If You Can Help Me Please Do, It's Been Driving Me *CRAZY* - Thanks :D

Comment: Use a relative path.  Put the shape file in the same directory as the `.py` file and use just the filename.

Comment: I could do this, but I want it, preferably, to be in organised folders

Comment: OK, then put another directory with your `.py` file and store the images in there.  Then use the relative path to that directory.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for expanduser lib. Please have a try this:

```
import os

def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)

dir = find('image.gif', os.path.expanduser("~"))
```

where os.path.expanduser("~") is a path to the "C:\Users\Username Here". So It will take some time to search a whole directory. Please use more specific directory if it's possible, for instance:

```
dir = find('image.gif', "%s\%s" %(os.path.expanduser("~"), "MyProject\Images"))
```

or use the relative directory if it's good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen you need to use a relative path from your `Game` directory (assuming this is the working directory for your game).

Eg. "Game\Images\an image.gif"